# SSRS nested if conditional formatting

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, sql-server-2012, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

I have this code in javascript that conditionally color the a data table. I would like to apply the same color conditions with same precedence to the SSRS report; so "rejected"(blue) will take precedence over "expired"(Red).

blue:Rejected 
Yellow:Pending
Red:Expired
Orange:Warning 
Approved:white 
empty:white unless rejected then blue even though it is empty.

#### Javascript code with the logic that I want

```
    if (status == '1') 
      {
                        return 'rejected';
                    } 
                    else if (status == '3') 
                    {
                        return 'pending';
                    }
                     else if (status == '5') 
                     {
                        if (celldate < currentdate) 
                        {
                            return 'expired';
                        } 
                        else if (celldate < warningdate && celldate > currentdate) 
                        {
                            return 'warning';
                        } 
                        else 
                        {
                            return 'approved';
                        }
                    } 
   else 
                    {
                        return 'null';
                    };
}
```

#### SSRS Report code:

```
=iif(Fields!LICAPPRSTATUSID.Value="1","Blue",
iif(Fields!LICAPPRSTATUSID.Value="3","Yellow",
iif(Fields!EXPIRATIONDATE.Value < Today, "Red",
iif(Fields!EXPIRATIONDATE.Value < DateAdd("d",30,Today) and Fields!EXPIRATIONDATE.Value > Today, "Orange",
iif(IsNothing(Fields!EXPIRATIONDATE.Value),"White","White")))))
```

#### My Issue : the SSRS code is giving wrong precedence to the coloring condition

Comment: What are you expecting and what are you getting based on what data? Also, what are the values of other variables when you get wrong results?

Comment: @ViKiNG at the moment I am getting expired aka RED  instead of rejected aka Blue

Answer (score 0):

I would do this with SWITCH:

```
SWITCH
    (
    Fields!LICAPPRSTATUSID.Value="1","Blue",
    Fields!LICAPPRSTATUSID.Value="3","Yellow",
    Fields!LICAPPRSTATUSID.Value="5",
        SWITCH
            (
            Fields!EXPIRATIONDATE.Value < Today, "Red",
            Fields!EXPIRATIONDATE.Value < DateAdd("d",30,Today) and Fields!EXPIRATIONDATE.Value > Today, "Orange",
            IsNothing(Fields!EXPIRATIONDATE.Value),"White"
            )
    )
```

Note that the above code is a "best guess" based on how the variables in your SSRS code appear to map onto the variables in your javascript.

Do the cases in your javascript logic represent all cases?  If not, you'll probably want a default value at the end.  Bear in mind that the value associated with the FIRST condition that evaluates to true will be the one returned by the expression.

Comment: I have updated my post with colors.  Your code looks good but for some reason there must be a syntax error because the some of the words in the quotes are white instead of the orange color. I am trying to figure it out.   This should represent all cases .

Comment: Well, I wrote that at home, from memory :).  You can put that code in the expression editor for the background color expression, highlight the named color, and replace it using the color-selection palette in the bottom of the editor.

Comment: haha understood. I have it working regardless of the weird syntax code coloring(not error) but it still shows expired(red) before rejected(blue) which doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: I would have to see the data to troubleshoot further.  Based on the field LICAPPRStatusID, the "expired" and "rejected" recordsets should not overlap - based on your color description, "rejected" have a LICAPPRStatusID value of "1" but "expired" have a LICAPPRStatusID value of "5".

What, exactly, do you mean by "before"?

Comment: I really meant to say " instead of".  the licapprstatusid of this is for sure 1 so I do not see how the switch statement for 5 is activating.

Comment: Sure - you just have to define what "valid data" means :)

My typical approach is to make sure that the query that populates my resultset only returns valid data.  However, if the Status field is blank then the logic should not execute the inner SWITCH - you should only get "Red" if the Status field contains "5".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152670/discussion-between-brian-and-t-dang).